# Issues with managing entry box input with a list- Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a text editor application in Python tkinter. Every time a font is set, it is appended to a list. One of the features of the text editor is managing the font of the text. The issue is that after I change the font in one of the entry boxes, the next time I click on the `Font` button, The entry boxes input resets to its default input. Can someone help me find a solution for this issue? My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
import tkinter.font as tkfont
from tkinter import messagebox

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Text Editor")
window.configure(bg="white")
window.state("zoomed")
count = -1
my_list = []


def open_file():
    file_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")])

    if not file_path:
        return

    text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END)

    with open(file_path, "r") as file_read:
        text = file_read.read()
        text_box.insert(tk.END, text)


def save_file():
    file_path = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension="txt", filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")])

    if not file_path:
        return

    with open(file_path, "w") as file_write:
        text = text_box.get(1.0, tk.END)
        file_write.write(text)


def font_command(default_font):
    global count
    count += 1
    window2 = tk.Toplevel(window)
    window2.title("Font Name")
    window2.geometry("300x220+500+200")
    font_n = tk.Label(window2, text="Font:", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 10))
    font_n.place(x=50, y=80)
    name_entry = tk.Entry(window2)
    name_entry.place(x=50, y=110)
    font_size = tk.Label(window2, text="Font Size:", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 10))
    font_size.place(x=50, y=20)
    size_entry = tk.Entry(window2)
    size_entry.place(x=50, y=50)
    font_color = tk.Label(window2, text="Font Color:", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 10))
    font_color.place(x=50, y=140)
    color_entry = tk.Entry(window2)
    color_entry.place(x=50, y=170)
    color_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    color_entry.insert(tk.END, text_box["fg"])
    ok_button = tk.Button(window2, text="OK", width=8, height=2, bg="white",
                          command=lambda: check_font(size_entry.get(), name_entry.get(), color_entry.get(), window2))
    ok_button.place(x=210, y=100)

    if count == 0:
        name_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        name_entry.insert(tk.END, default_font["family"])
        size_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        size_entry.insert(tk.END, default_font["size"])
        my_list.append((name_entry.get(), size_entry.get()))
    else:
        name_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        name_entry.insert(tk.END, my_list[count - 1][0])
        size_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        size_entry.insert(tk.END, my_list[count - 1][1])
        my_list.append((name_entry.get(), size_entry.get()))


def check_font(size, font, color, root):
    try:
        font_settings = tkfont.Font(family=font, size=size)
        text_box.configure(fg=color, font=font_settings)
        root.destroy()
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Font Error", "Invalid Font!")


frame = tk.Frame(window, bd=2, relief="raised")
frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")

default_f = tkfont.Font(family="Courier New", size=10)
text_box = tk.Text(window, font=default_f, fg="black")
text_box.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=text_box.yview)
scroll_bar.pack(side="left", fill="y")

open_b = tk.Button(frame, text="Open", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=open_file)
open_b.pack(padx=50, pady=(100, 5), anchor="n")
save_b = tk.Button(frame, text="Save As", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=save_file)
save_b.pack(padx=50, pady=5)
font_info = tk.Button(frame, text="Font", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=lambda: font_command(default_f))
font_info.pack(padx=50, pady=5)

text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)

clear_text = tk.Button(frame, text="Clear All", width=6, height=2, bg="white",
                       command=lambda: text_box.delete(0, tk.END))
clear_text.pack(padx=50, pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You know that as soon as you create `name_entry`, you call `name_entry.get()` then append the result to your list. Shouldn't the `my_list.append((name_entry.get(), size_entry.get()))` be inside `check_font`?

Comment: You are deleting everything from the ```Entry```

Comment: @TheLizzard, I moved the append part to the check_font function, but now the messagebox pops up every time saying the font is invalid even though it is valid

Comment: I'll update the code so you can see what I did

Comment: Never mind, I managed to fix it

Comment: @Roni Can you please move the solution to answer? It will make it easier for anyone that encounters this problem in the future

Comment: I edited my question, but I can add it as an answer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem with the help of @TheLizzard! The changes that I've made: I moved the `my_list.append((font, size))` part to the `try` clause in the `check_file` function because I wanted to append the font attributes to the list only after the `OK` button was clicked, rather than right after creating the widgets in the `font_command` function. In the `except` clause, I'm also decrementing count by 1, so that if a user inputs a font which throws an error, it won't be counted.
Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
import tkinter.font as tkfont
from tkinter import messagebox

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Text Editor")
window.configure(bg="white")
window.state("zoomed")
count = -1
my_list = []


def open_file():
    file_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")])

    if not file_path:
        return

    text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END)

    with open(file_path, "r") as file_read:
        text = file_read.read()
        text_box.insert(tk.END, text)


def save_file():
    file_path = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension="txt", filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")])

    if not file_path:
        return

    with open(file_path, "w") as file_write:
        text = text_box.get(1.0, tk.END)
        file_write.write(text)


def font_command(default_font):
    global count
    count += 1
    window2 = tk.Toplevel(window)
    window2.title("Font Name")
    window2.geometry("300x220+500+200")
    font_n = tk.Label(window2, text="Font:", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 10))
    font_n.place(x=50, y=80)
    name_entry = tk.Entry(window2)
    name_entry.place(x=50, y=110)
    font_size = tk.Label(window2, text="Font Size:", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 10))
    font_size.place(x=50, y=20)
    size_entry = tk.Entry(window2)
    size_entry.place(x=50, y=50)
    font_color = tk.Label(window2, text="Font Color:", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 10))
    font_color.place(x=50, y=140)
    color_entry = tk.Entry(window2)
    color_entry.place(x=50, y=170)
    color_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    color_entry.insert(tk.END, text_box["fg"])
    ok_button = tk.Button(window2, text="OK", width=8, height=2, bg="white",
                          command=lambda: check_font(size_entry.get(), name_entry.get(), color_entry.get(), window2))
    ok_button.place(x=210, y=100)

    if count == 0:
        name_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        name_entry.insert(tk.END, default_font["family"])
        size_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        size_entry.insert(tk.END, default_font["size"])
    else:
        name_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        name_entry.insert(tk.END, my_list[count - 1][0])
        size_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        size_entry.insert(tk.END, my_list[count - 1][1])


def check_font(size, font, color, root):
    global count
    try:
        font_settings = tkfont.Font(family=font, size=size)
        text_box.configure(fg=color, font=font_settings)
        root.destroy()
        my_list.append((font, size))
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Font Error", "Invalid Font!")
        count -= 1


frame = tk.Frame(window, bd=2, relief="raised")
frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")

default_f = tkfont.Font(family="Courier New", size=10)
text_box = tk.Text(window, font=default_f, fg="black")
text_box.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=text_box.yview)
scroll_bar.pack(side="left", fill="y")

open_b = tk.Button(frame, text="Open", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=open_file)
open_b.pack(padx=50, pady=(100, 5), anchor="n")
save_b = tk.Button(frame, text="Save As", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=save_file)
save_b.pack(padx=50, pady=5)
font_info = tk.Button(frame, text="Font", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=lambda: font_command(default_f))
font_info.pack(padx=50, pady=5)

text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)

clear_text = tk.Button(frame, text="Clear All", width=6, height=2, bg="white",
                       command=lambda: text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END))
clear_text.pack(padx=50, pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you described what you did. Otherwise, people coming here with a similar problem will have to compare this code to the code in the question line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you changed.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, you’re right, I’ll edit it in a couple hours when I’m next to my pc